# Is there a way to automatically format an excel cell to a friendly hyperlink when a user pastes in a full URL?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

I am building out a spreadsheet where I want to paste in a long and ugly link into a cell. I would like automated formatting to take place that will take that long link and create a "friendly" link instead. I am trying to save the steps of going into link menu to do this. I don't know if there is an easy way to do this, or do I need some macros.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What rules are used to determine what to name the friendly link? If you don't mind have more than one column, then you could have the long URL in one column, then the friendly name in another column by using a hyperlink formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this macro in your ThisWorkbook module:

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub PasteFriendlyURL()

    Dim myLink As Hyperlink
    Dim displayText As String
    
    displayText = ""
    
    displayText = InputBox("Enter the display text for your URL")
    
    If displayText = "" Then
        displayText = "Pasted Link"
    End If
    
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
    Set myLink = ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Value)
    
    myLink.TextToDisplay = displayText

End Sub
```

I have added the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to use this macro by editing the Options in the Macro dialog from Excel (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> will open the Macro dialog):

[image]

So, I copy a link, then select a cell and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>:

[image]

This will of course not behave well if what you've copied is not a valid URL. You can choose whether to write some error handling into the procedure. Depending on who is going to use it, it may be fine as is or you may need to make it more robust.

Answer (score 0):

[FlexYourData's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1688267/348859) is a good one, especially if you're used to using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to enter hyperlinks. Depending on your use case, you could also write a VBA routine that triggers each time you add text that Excel auto-formats into a hyperlink. I wrote the example below that lives in the ThisWorkbook module and triggers every time you add a hyperlink in any sheet. You may want to tweak things like the message text or limit it to a particular sheet.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim url As String
    Dim msg As String
    Dim txt As String
    On Error Resume Next
    url = Target.Hyperlinks(1).Address
    If Len(url) > 0 Then
        msg = "It looks like you've pasted a hyperlink. Would you like to display friendly text instead of the URL?"
        If MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Format Hyperlink") = vbYes Then
            txt = InputBox("Friendly text to display instead of the URL:", "Format Hyperlink", url)
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Hyperlinks.Add Target, url, , , txt
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I know of at least one quirk where pasting a hyperlink into multiple cells will trigger the event but it will only edit the hyperlink of the top-left cell. I imagine that's not common, though. It will *also* trigger whenever you create hyperlink that's already friendly via Insert Hyperlink within Excel.

[image: GIF]